# Multiple select array not sending data

Tags: php, html, arrays, select

as ussual I wanted to use multiple select.

```
<select  multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="kraj[]">
<option value="1">Středočeský</option>
<option value="2">Jihočeský</option>
<option value="3">Plzeňský</option>
<option value="4">Jihomoravský</option>
<option value="5">Vysočina</option>
<option value="6">Moravskoslezský</option>
<option value="7">Ústecký</option>
<option value="8">Olomoucký</option>
<option value="9">Kralovehradecký</option>
<option value="10">Pardubický</option>
<option value="11">Zlínský</option>
<option value="12">Karlovehradecký</option>
<option value="13">Liberecký</option>
<option value="14">Praha</option>
```

But this time i am not getting data from this. Other parts of form working properly but after selecting some options i get an empty array of kraj[]. print_r looks like:

`Array
(   ...

```
[delka] => 5000

[kraj] => 

[onoffswitch] => on
...
```

)`

I just cant see, what is wrong, im kinda desperate. Deadline tommorow, and stuck at this :D

Comment: Tried with `name="kraj"` ?

Comment: Did you close the select?

Comment: yes, select is closed. when you puy just name="kraj", it will send just one value. I need multiple.

Comment: and web browser console that sends in that array "kraj"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

HTML:

```
       <form method="POST" >         
           <select  multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="kraj[]">
            <option value="1">Středočeský</option>
            <option value="2">Jihočeský</option>
            <option value="3">Plzeňský</option>
            <option value="4">Jihomoravský</option>

            etc
          </select>

           <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
       </form>
```

PHP:

```
             if(isset($_POST)){

                     foreach ($_POST['kraj'] as $selectedOpt){
                        echo $selectedOpt."\n";                 
                     }                  
                }

         echo "<pre>";
             print_r($_POST);
         echo "</pre>";
```

OUTPUT:

```
                 Array
                (
                    [kraj] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 2
                            [2] => 3
                        )

                )
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate your issue - your script works as intended.

Tried the following:

```
<?php

if (sizeof($_POST)) {
    var_dump($_POST);
}

?>
<form method="post" action="">
<select  multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="kraj[]">
    <option value="1">Středočeský</option>
    <option value="2">Jihočeský</option>
    <option value="3">Plzeňský</option>
    <option value="4">Jihomoravský</option>
    <option value="5">Vysočina</option>
    <option value="6">Moravskoslezský</option>
    <option value="7">Ústecký</option>
    <option value="8">Olomoucký</option>
    <option value="9">Kralovehradecký</option>
    <option value="10">Pardubický</option>
    <option value="11">Zlínský</option>
    <option value="12">Karlovehradecký</option>
    <option value="13">Liberecký</option>
    <option value="14">Praha</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

After submit:

[image]

Comment: That bug was elsewhere. Our company have "new cool custom framework" and it discarded whole array, while filtering XSS. Thx for help :)